# Remove SharePoint2013 logo and App Name

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, app, site-logo

I am deploying a SharePoint2013 App (SharePoint hosted).
How can I remove the SharePoint2013 Logo and the App name?
I tried this in `document.ready`

```
$("#titleAreaRow").hide();
$("#DeltaWebPartAdderUpdatePanelContainer").hide();
```

But I can still see the logo for a while.How can I fix it?

Thank,
Nk

Comment: I think a better solution is described [here](https://www.fpweb.net/blog/how-to-change-the-logo-on-your-sharepoint-2013-site/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with CSS in your default.aspx file with:

```
#s4-titlerow{
    display:none!important;
}
```

This will hide the complete title area (with breadcrumb and title).

Doing it with javascript is tricky since SharePoint seems to set `display:block` on the element with javascript as well. So if you want to go in that direction you need to find out what JS script is setting it to display, and try to run your script afterwards.

Comment: Do you know how can I hide the top "ribbon" (Newsfeed,OneDrive,Sites....).
I need to hide them to print the page.
Thanks